# Pivoting a pandas dataframe using the first column as colNames

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, transpose

I know how the pivot_table works in python. However I have a different problem. My sample dataframe ( or csv file say) looks this below:

```
        df 

        
       PRD    A1    A2     A3     A4    A5    A6   A7 

       DN     12    67-1    34    98    07    45   29

       AV    uy-9   iu-9    uyt   tr    uytq  hbg   nba

       PVAL   12.9   1.9    2.3   3.9    6.9  8.0   12
```

However I way I want my data is like this below:

```
              df 

                 PRD         DN          AV         PVAL 

                  A1         12          uy-9       12.9
                  A2         67-1        iu-9        1.9
                  A3         34          uyt         2.3
                  A4         98           tr         3.9
                  A5         07          uytq        6.9
                  A6         45           hbg        8.0
                  A7         29           nba        12
```

I was trying to use pd.pivot_table, however not sure how to specify the dynamic column names or values.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is transpose, not pivot. `df.set_index('PRD').T`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to change rows and columns in pandas:

- Use pandas.DataFrame.T

```
df_transposed = df.T
```

- Use pandas.DataFrame.transpose

```
df_transposed = df.transpose()
```

**Note**

depending on the data type dtype of each column, a view is created instead of a copy, and changing the value of one of the original and transposed objects will change the other.

In `transpose()`, a copy is always generated if `copy` is set to `True`.

```
df_t_copy = df.transpose(copy=True)
```